# Java instance methods: not just overriden, but also hidden

Tags: java, methods, instance, hidden

As a **newb** (edited: wrote **noob** instead) as I can be, the official Java tutorial, in the very bottom of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html, states that static methods are HIDDEN in subclasses that reimplement them, whereas instance methods are plainly OVERRIDEN.

But in the section http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html of the same tutorial, one has the ability to call the superclass' overriden method from inside the overriding method (and possibly from other methods).

Please excuse some excess of purism from my part, but from that I can only conclude that instance methods are not only OVERRIDEN, but also HIDDEN.

Thoughts?

Comment: That's the terminology, you can disagree with the names and that's okay as long as you understand the meaning. Voting to close the question as "opinion based"

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us whether your reasoning is correct? Whether your conclusion is true? Or what hiding or overriding actually mean?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1

Comment: The terminology describes a specific case where "hidden method" is used as a noun; this question tries to apply "hidden" as an adjective to a different situation.

Comment: I didn't mean to insult anyone's intelligence or opinion. I'm new to Java and those concepts I mentioned kept my poor brains itching for a night, thus I needed a second opinion. BTW English isn't my native language either, thus in the original post I wrote "noob" instead of "newb", due to some bad advice I got. Thanks everyone, especially http://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis for the JLS section listing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for an evaluation of your reasoning. The definition of polymorphism is a changing in functionality, in the subclass, that previously existed in the superclass. So yes, it hides it because the interface of an overriding subclass no longer provides access to the superclass method from outside of the class, in favour of the subclass implementation.

**Example**

So we've got a superclass:

```
public abstract class Person {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Person is speaking!");
    }
}
```

And we create our subclass:

```
public class Male {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I like beer and code.");
    }
}
```

The `Male` class hides the `Person` implementation of the `speak` method. So in that sense, it is hidden. But, the superclass method can be accessed from inside the `Male` class.

```
public void speak() {
    super.speak();
    System.out.println("I like beer and code.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation makes sense, but don't let it confuse you. The important part is *overriding*, this is something you have to understand.

I would not call an overridden method "*hidden*" as it's still available, though via a different implementation. That's the sense of overriding.

Concerning *hiding* of static methods, just forget it. Doing it is allowed, but it buys you nothing at all. Nobody uses it and you should not either. Just forget it.